# Setting time variable via textbox in Twincat 3 HMI

Tags: time, textbox, plc, twincat

With variables such as integer, float or string I used **Write To Symbol** to write the variable to  the PLC with the HMI textbox under **.onTextChanged** in the properties window (see images below).
[image: Write To Symbol]
[image: Properties window]

But it won't work with the Time variable.
How can I make this work without changing the PLC code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never worked with javascript before, but that is where I found the sollution.
I also used **.onUserInteractionFinished** instead of **.onTextChanged** like displayed in image underneath:

[image: Properties Window]

After that I wrote this javascript code:

```
(function (TcHmi) {

    var CheckTextboxForNumber = function (Textbox) {
        //get content from the textbox
        var _text = Textbox.getText();
        //convert to time variable in 
        if (!_text.startsWith('PT')) {
            var _value = Number(_text);
            Textbox.setText('PT' + _value.toFixed(3) + 'S');
            return _value.toFixed(3);
        }
    };

    TcHmi.Functions.registerFunction('CheckTextboxForNumber', CheckTextboxForNumber);
})(TcHmi);
```

I put the code in before the **Write To Symbol**, with an added rounding, because the rounding is done differently after the 3th decimal: when I tested it without rounding the decimals, starting with the 4th, the PLC would display other decimals then I input in the HMI textbox.

What I input in the 'actions and conditons' window can be seen in below image:

[image: Writing variable to PLC]

After that it worked as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the object "Numeric input" on the TC Hmi to write variable in the PLC, with the event ".onUserInteractionFinished". it should work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXHo6.png)